# On user comments history page, the "Select all" checkbox does not work after performing a search

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, user-comments-page

*This is a bug report about a moderator-only feature.*

---

Recently, the user comments history page was revamped, and bulk actions as well as comments search was implemented. Both work fine separately.

However, after performing a search (AJAX call), the bulk actions "Select all" checkbox no longer functions, and clicking on it does not select/unselect all the search results.

[image: screenshot]

Also, selecting any of the individual checkboxes below does not enable the bulk actions "Actions" dropdown at the top.

---

Windows 10 Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit), userscripts switched off

Comment: My userscript [CommentFlagsHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentFlagsHelper.user.js) temporarily fixes this by ignoring the official ajax request and redirects the entire page to the search results. This results in a wasted server request per search/pagination change.

Comment: Thanks for raising - this is on our list to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this fix built out today! The AJAX call that reloads the table was messing up the bulk select option. Thanks for finding it