# On user comments history page, the comment search is case-sensitive. Can it please be made case-insensitive?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, user-comments-page

*This is a bug report about a moderator-only feature.*

---

Recently, the user comments history page was revamped, and comments search was implemented.

However, the search and results when searching comments are case-sensitive.

E.g.: If I were to search for comments with "abcdef", the results will **not** show comments with "Abcdef" or "ABCDEF", etc.

This makes it difficult to find all instances of the search term, and moderators who may not be aware of this to miss out on several instances of the searched term in user's comments, especially when trying to search for and delete offensive comments made by users.

I consider this to be a bug, since the main Q&A search is case-insensitive, and this comments search should be as well.

Comment: _"the user comments history page was revamped, and comments search was implemented"_ Really? I can finally search through my comments without using SEDE? _"This is a bug report about a moderator-only feature"_ Okay, Imma head out. `*cries in normal-user privileges*`

Comment: It looks like [search on this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348614/on-user-comments-history-page-the-select-all-checkbox-does-not-work-after-per) needs to be revisited, so going to look into this along with the other report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just built out the fixes for this- we did some optimization for loading so hopefully the page will be a bit faster as well.